# Error during migration process using GCP's Database Migration Service for MySQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I'm receiving the following error during migration process using GCP Database Migration Service for MySQL:

> failed to run mysqldump: import err = generic::unknown: exit status 1 ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 46092: Access denied for user 'cloudsqlimport'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO), mysqldump error = exit status 5, stderr: mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. mysqldump: Got errno 2 on write

How can I solve that?

Comment: You may doublecheck the steps you have taken with the steps noted in the [DMS quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/quickstart) to make sure you haven't missed any step to configure the migration job and also doublecheck your [connectivity configuration](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/configure-connectivity).

Comment: If your migration job containing metadata with DEFINER clause, keep in mind that you need to [create the users on your target Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/mysql-definer) before starting your migration job.

If the issue still persists, I recommend to report it via a [PRIVATE Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130) and provide us with the required information denoted in the ticket so that we would be able to dig into the issue.

Comment: @Katayoon, I double-check all steps. I think it is something related to the user 'cloudsqlimport'@'127.0.0.1' created during the process. I'm still investigating. But thanks for your insights!

Comment: @Katayoon, you were right! I missed a user that was on DEFINER! Now everything is ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Katayoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394595/katayoon) was right in her [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835789/error-during-migration-process-using-gcps-database-migration-service-for-mysql#comment114637700_64835789)! I didn't create a user that was on DEFINER in the replica database!

For reference:
https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/mysql-definer

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do the migration manually.

Run mysqldump yourself to a file.

Then load this text file back into the new database.

Check out this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers).